# mongodb suddenly stopped working on production server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pm2, ubuntu-server

I have a server running node and mongoDB. Mongo is suddenly throwing errors, I managed to get it started upon rebooting the server but the error reappears upon trying to handle a request.

The error when I try to run mongo in a shell is:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

My mongod.conf has the correct data path and I also tried setting it manually using `mongod --dbpath` and can confirm that it is correct.

`mongod --repair` doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like `mongod` service is either not running. what does `sudo service mongod status` show? might have some clue as to why it's not running.

Comment: It says loaded but active: failed. No reason why.

Comment: do `sudo service mongod start` and see what error messages it spits out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the server was out of storage. Running `df` showed that there was no disk space left.

I ended up adding a volume and moving my database and files there.